# PHP equivalent of Java's Character.getNumericValue(char c)?

Tags: java, php, unicode

Is there a PHP equivalent of Java's [`Character.getNumericValue(char c)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There are no baked in equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the `intval()` function.**

This will not handle letters or roman numerals the same way, but you could create your own method to do that for those cases.  It will handle standard digits, though.

```
if (intval("2") === 2)
  echo("YAY!");
```

Comment: `intval` is indeed interesting. Using base 36 should make it handle letters as well.

Answer (score 0):

[`ord`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

**Edit:** Oops, that's not what [`getNumericValue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) does. I guess the answer is no then. You'll have to make up a table of your own that maps numeric characters to numbers.

If you want a function that works with the most common numeric characters, you could do something like this, but it would fail for special Unicode numerals:

```
function getNumericValue($ch) {
  if (ctype_digit($ch))
    return ord($ch) - ord('0');
  if (ctype_upper($ch))
    return ord($ch) - ord('A') + 10;
  if (ctype_lower($ch))
    return ord($ch) - ord('a') + 10;
  return -1;
}
```